# Mobile-First Responsive Design IE 8 Widescreen Compatibility

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design, respond.js

Here is a **[link to the page I'm working on](http://warriors.com/premium-suites-testing).**

I've switched over to Bootstrap 3's mobile-first framework. The main difference is that instead of defaulting to a wide layout and using media queries to shrink down to mobile sizes, the default size is mobile and media queries are used to for wider resolutions:

So instead of:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {}
```

We now use:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {}
```

**When using the old way, IE 8 (which doesn't support media queries) would display the page in its widest format. However now it displays the page in its mobile format, which is not desirable.**

Is there any way to get the page to default to the widest layout when media queries are not supported? I include respond.js but have had no luck:

```
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: I see that you are using and if lt ie 9 so why not including there a custom width for the container and there you have it, since the col-lg * uses % widths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix that gets you a long way:
Add a stylesheet for ltie9

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link href="styles/css/ltie9.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
```

Copy and paste the styling for cols, push and offset from the media query of your choosing (You find this in grid.less) into `ltie9.less`. i.ex. the medium size:

*Its has to be less, you need to include `variables.less` as well. Or you can replace all the widths width a percentage of your choosing, but why would you?*

```
// Core variables
@import "variables.less";

body {
  .container {
    max-width: @container-desktop;
  }
  .col-md-1,
  .col-md-2,
  .col-md-3,
  .col-md-4,
  .col-md-5,
  .col-md-6,
  .col-md-7,
  .col-md-8,
  .col-md-9,
  .col-md-10,
  .col-md-11 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-1  { width: percentage((1 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-2  { width: percentage((2 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-3  { width: percentage((3 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-4  { width: percentage((4 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-5  { width: percentage((5 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-6  { width: percentage((6 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-7  { width: percentage((7 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-8  { width: percentage((8 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-9  { width: percentage((9 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-10 { width: percentage((10/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-11 { width: percentage((11/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-12 { width: 100%; }

  // Push and pull columns for source order changes
  .col-md-push-0  { left: auto; }
  .col-md-push-1  { left: percentage((1 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-2  { left: percentage((2 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-3  { left: percentage((3 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-4  { left: percentage((4 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-5  { left: percentage((5 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-6  { left: percentage((6 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-7  { left: percentage((7 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-8  { left: percentage((8 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-9  { left: percentage((9 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-10 { left: percentage((10/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-push-11 { left: percentage((11/ @grid-columns)); }

  .col-md-pull-0  { right: auto; }
  .col-md-pull-1  { right: percentage((1 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-2  { right: percentage((2 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-3  { right: percentage((3 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-4  { right: percentage((4 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-5  { right: percentage((5 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-6  { right: percentage((6 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-7  { right: percentage((7 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-8  { right: percentage((8 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-9  { right: percentage((9 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-10 { right: percentage((10/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-pull-11 { right: percentage((11/ @grid-columns)); }

  // Offsets
  .col-md-offset-0  { margin-left: 0; }
  .col-md-offset-1  { margin-left: percentage((1 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-2  { margin-left: percentage((2 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-3  { margin-left: percentage((3 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-4  { margin-left: percentage((4 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-5  { margin-left: percentage((5 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-6  { margin-left: percentage((6 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-7  { margin-left: percentage((7 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-8  { margin-left: percentage((8 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-9  { margin-left: percentage((9 / @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-10 { margin-left: percentage((10/ @grid-columns)); }
  .col-md-offset-11 { margin-left: percentage((11/ @grid-columns)); }
}
```